# need help about opening dicom file in matlab

Tags: matlab, dicom

i got black image when opening dicom file in matlab

my code for opening dicom files

```
[real_image,real_path] = uigetfile( ...
{'*.*;','File Dicom (*.dcm)';},...
'Open Image');

if ~isequal(real_image,0)
handles.image = dicomread(fullfile(real_path,real_image));
guidata(hObject,handles);
axes(handles.axes1);
imshow(handles.image);

set(handles.text5,'String',real_image);
set(handles.text6,'String',real_path);

[row,column]=size(handles.image);
set(handles.text7,'String',row);
set(handles.text8,'String',column);

else
return;
end
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've tested your code by creating a GUI (R2012b) and inserting the code in pushbutton callback and it works fine.

So I can see two possibilities:
- the `dcom` image you are loading in somehow corrupted
- the `dcom` image is good and it is a probelm of `contrast`

I'll go for the second possibility.

I've used, as examples, the `dcom` images "CARDIX" downloaded from [DICOM sample image sets](http://www.osirix-viewer.com/datasets/).

As one of these images is loaded, it appears to be black and the axes's `clim` is `[0 65535`].

If you set the `clim` range to, respectively, the `minimum` and `maximum` values of the dcom image data value, you can start "seeing something".

To further enhance the visibility of the image you can use the [imcontrast tool](http://uk.mathworks.com/help/images/ref/imcontrast.html).

[image]

In the following you can find the `.m` file of the GUI: the `imcontrast tool` can be run through a `pushbutton`.

```
function varargout = adjust_contrast(varargin)
% ADJUST_CONTRAST MATLAB code for adjust_contrast.fig
%      ADJUST_CONTRAST, by itself, creates a new ADJUST_CONTRAST or raises the existing
%      singleton*.
%
%      H = ADJUST_CONTRAST returns the handle to a new ADJUST_CONTRAST or the handle to
%      the existing singleton*.
%
%      ADJUST_CONTRAST('CALLBACK',hObject,eventData,handles,...) calls the local
%      function named CALLBACK in ADJUST_CONTRAST.M with the given input arguments.
%
%      ADJUST_CONTRAST('Property','Value',...) creates a new ADJUST_CONTRAST or raises the
%      existing singleton*.  Starting from the left, property value pairs are
%      applied to the GUI before adjust_contrast_OpeningFcn gets called.  An
%      unrecognized property name or invalid value makes property application
%      stop.  All inputs are passed to adjust_contrast_OpeningFcn via varargin.
%
%      *See GUI Options on GUIDE's Tools menu.  Choose "GUI allows only one
%      instance to run (singleton)".
%
% See also: GUIDE, GUIDATA, GUIHANDLES

% Edit the above text to modify the response to help adjust_contrast

% Last Modified by GUIDE v2.5 26-Dec-2015 10:44:54

% Begin initialization code - DO NOT EDIT
gui_Singleton = 1;
gui_State = struct('gui_Name',       mfilename, ...
                   'gui_Singleton',  gui_Singleton, ...
                   'gui_OpeningFcn', @adjust_contrast_OpeningFcn, ...
                   'gui_OutputFcn',  @adjust_contrast_OutputFcn, ...
                   'gui_LayoutFcn',  [] , ...
                   'gui_Callback',   []);
if nargin && ischar(varargin{1})
    gui_State.gui_Callback = str2func(varargin{1});
end

if nargout
    [varargout{1:nargout}] = gui_mainfcn(gui_State, varargin{:});
else
    gui_mainfcn(gui_State, varargin{:});
end
% End initialization code - DO NOT EDIT


% --- Executes just before adjust_contrast is made visible.
function adjust_contrast_OpeningFcn(hObject, eventdata, handles, varargin)
% This function has no output args, see OutputFcn.
% hObject    handle to figure
% eventdata  reserved - to be defined in a future version of MATLAB
% handles    structure with handles and user data (see GUIDATA)
% varargin   command line arguments to adjust_contrast (see VARARGIN)

% Choose default command line output for adjust_contrast
handles.output = hObject;

% Update handles structure
guidata(hObject, handles);

% UIWAIT makes adjust_contrast wait for user response (see UIRESUME)
% uiwait(handles.figure1);


% --- Outputs from this function are returned to the command line.
function varargout = adjust_contrast_OutputFcn(hObject, eventdata, handles) 
% varargout  cell array for returning output args (see VARARGOUT);
% hObject    handle to figure
% eventdata  reserved - to be defined in a future version of MATLAB
% handles    structure with handles and user data (see GUIDATA)

% Get default command line output from handles structure
varargout{1} = handles.output;


% --- Executes on button press in pushbutton1.
function pushbutton1_Callback(hObject, eventdata, handles)
% hObject    handle to pushbutton1 (see GCBO)
% eventdata  reserved - to be defined in a future version of MATLAB
% handles    structure with handles and user data (see GUIDATA)


[real_image,real_path] = uigetfile( ...
   {'*.dcm;','File Dicom (*.dcm)';},...
   'Open Image');

if ~isequal(real_image,0)
   handles.image = dicomread(fullfile(real_path,real_image));
   guidata(hObject,handles);
   axes(handles.axes1);
   imshow(handles.image);

   set(handles.text5,'String',real_image);
   set(handles.text6,'String',real_path);

   [row,column]=size(handles.image);
   set(handles.text7,'String',row);
   set(handles.text8,'String',column);

else
   return;
end
% Set the "Clim" scale to the [min max] image values
set(gca,'clim',[min(min(handles.image)) max(max(handles.image))])


% --- Executes on button press in pushbutton2.
function pushbutton2_Callback(hObject, eventdata, handles)
% hObject    handle to pushbutton2 (see GCBO)
% eventdata  reserved - to be defined in a future version of MATLAB
% handles    structure with handles and user data (see GUIDATA)

imcontrast
```

In the following picture you can see:
- the "black" image as it appears as loaded
- the first enhacement following the updating of the `clim` range
- the enhancements obtained "working" with the `imcontrast tool`

Notice: you can download a [DCOMViewer](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/4172-dicom-viewer) from MATLAB Central.

Hope this helps.

[image]